# No. Of ways to put numbers in a grid

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

Let every cell of adjoining 3×3 array is filled by natural number such that
$x_1x_2x_3 = y_1y_2y_3 $= $2^33^45^7$

where $ x_i y_j$
are product of numbers filled in three
cells of $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column respectively i, j € {1, 2, 3},
[image]

Then no. Of ways such that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are both divisible by 2

The only thing I could think of was that the case is similar to putting

3 identical(no. 2) balls ,4 identical (no. 3 )balls, 7 identical (no. 5 )balls in 9 different boxes. Can someone provide me a hint to how to count the cases

Comment: There are only a few ways to place all the $2$'s in those nine boxes so that every row and every columns has a $2$; figure those out first. Once you have placed the two's, the threes can be scatter arbitrarily. The number of ways to place $4$ identical threes is $9$ distinct boxes can be found with stars and bars. Same goes for the fives. I think this all should be enough of a hint to make some progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_i  and y_i$ both are divisible by 2 and 2 has a power 3 each row and column must have one 2

No. Of ways to distribute $2^3$

3c1×2c1×1c1

Now each number is each box can be written as
$A_i=3^{a_i}.5^{b_i}$  because 2 has already been distributed

And $A_1×A_2......A_9=3^4×5^7$

1. $a_1+a_2.....a_9=4$  12c8 ways
2. $b_1+b_2.....b_9=7$ 15c8 ways

Final answer  6×12c4×15c8